# Issue in UITableView without cell reuse

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios7

I am trying to create a tableview without reusing cells.

In the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
cell = [[SignUpUserCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                     reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.delegate = self;
return cell;

}
```

However this does not load my custom cells. but when I add dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier: it works perfectly. However I donot want cell re use.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    SignUpUserCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[SignUpUserCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                     reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.keyLabel.text = [parameterDictionary objectForKey:@"secondLabel"];
    cell.textField.text = [parameterDictionary objectForKey:@"secondField"];

    // and some more elements

    cell.delegate = self;
    return cell;
}
```

How to properly create a tableview with non reusable tablecells. What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: why not using reusable cells which is strongly recommended and powerful.

Comment: Your first block of code doesn't actually compile because `cell` is not defined.  So I'm guessing what you have there is not correct.  For what it's worth, I was able to get it working by declaring `cell` on my sample project, but you should re-use the cells if possible.

Comment: What you are doing wrong is "not doing what Apple wants you to do". In the Apple world, this is a deadly mistake. While you can succeed, occasionaly, the real solution is to follow Apple's documentation and recommended techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this is the code you are actually using?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
cell = [[SignUpUserCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.delegate = self;
return cell;

   }
```

The reason I ask is you are not defining what `cell` is, should't the code be this...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
SignUpUserCell * cell = [[SignUpUserCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.delegate = self;
return cell;

   }
```

Comment: Actually sorry for my mistake. I have correctly declared SignUpUserCell * cell in my code. So what do you think is the issue? My code is same as the corrected code added here, and it is not simply cell.

Comment: What does your `SignUpUserCell` look like? Are you defining it in a nib?

Comment: No, I am using a story board.

Comment: OK, so have you set up the custom class name in the properties and does your identifier match what you've entered in the storyboard. It would help if you showed some screen shots? As others have already pointed out you should really be using reusable cells

Answer (score 0):

needs to be:

```
return cell;
```

not

```
return self;
```